# How to subtract vectors stored in two lists in R?

Tags: r

I'm dealing with an issue right now. I have to choose between 40 different splines each one with a different degree of freedom. I got for each one of these the predicted values with the fucntion predict and I stored each set of predicted values in a vector contained in a list.I want to subtract to each one of these vectors the vector of my true values. I declare a new empty list where I will save each of these differences. I a for loop but when I try to access to a whatever vector in this new list I get NULL  as result. I leave to you some lines of code to get a clearer Idea

Thanx in advance!!

```
#here I loop out my predicted values for each degree of freedom

Pred <- list()

for (i in length(seq(1,40))){
Pred[[i]] <- predict(smooth.spline(x,y),x)$y)
}
#Here I create the new list to store each difference
Diff <- list()
for( i in length(seq(1,40))){
Diff[[i]] <- y - Pred[[i]]
}
# If you try to access to any of Diff[[i]] you will get null
```

Comment: for( i in length(seq(1,40))){print(i)} ; you are only looping through i = 40; it should be just for i in 1:40

Comment: also, in your first loop, Pred[[i]] <- predict(smooth.spline(x,y),x)$y), you are always getting the same value...

Comment: You are right thanx. In the second portion of the problem when I try to get differences between actual data and predicted one, it returns me : "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". You can refer to the Diff for loop part in my post. Thanx in advance!

Comment: can you do df=data.frame(x,y); dput(df) ; and paste the output.. i still don't get what you are looping with this Pred[[i]] <- predict(smooth.spline(x,y),x)$y)

Comment: 'set.seed(2701)
generated= function(n){
x <- sort(runif(n,0,8))
eps <- rnorm(n,0,0.5)
y=sin(x)+eps

return(data.frame(x=x,y=y))
}
n=1000


L=generated(n)

x <- L$generated

y <- L$generated

plot(x,y, type = 'p', col = 'red', pch=16)'

Comment: ok so with every loop you generate a new x and y, and smooth it? Sorry I cannot just read code and know instantly what you want to do...

Comment: I'll asnwer to you this evening when I come back from work. Sorry for the delay

Comment: It was a messy week. Anyway I solved it!